# How do you load external javascript libraries in a ractive component?

Tags: ractivejs, ractive-load

I am trying to componentize some of my html pages to make them ractive components and load them using ractive-load.  I don't use any build system or "tools" (i.e. grunt, browserify, require, etc)

I am getting the error:

```
You can only have one <script> tag per component file
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My Title</title>

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="static/jquery-2.1.4/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
    <script src='static/ractive-0.7.3/ractive.js'></script> 
    <script src='static/ractiveload/ractive-load.js' ></script> -->
    <script src='static/app.js' ></script> 

  </head>

  <body>

        <header>
                <a href='/'>My Title</a>
        </header> 

        <!-- This is a dynamic div that is loaded on-demand by ractive. -->
        <div class='wrapper' id='mainPanel'>
        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    Ractive.load('views/control.html').then( function(Control){
        var ractive = new Control({
            el: "#mainPanel",
        });
    }).
```

views/control.html:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="static/some/lib.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="static/some/otherlib.js"></script>


<div>This is a test</div>
```

How do I load additional JavaScript libraries into a Ractive component?

Comment: It seems that I may be able to "require" dependencies, but I am not sure if that includes javascript libraries. [link](https://github.com/ractivejs/component-spec/blob/master/authors.md)

Answer (score 0):

When using single-file components, you use the special `require` function. Note that this function is not, in any way, tied to any tool's implementation. It may, however, be an abstraction of the underlying tool's implementation.

But the component spec mentions that `require`'s behavior is dependent on the loader being used. In the case of ractive-load, its dependency management is not very sophisticated. Its behavior is to find the dependency in `Ractive.load.modules` or the global `window` if it's not found in the previous. This can only mean that your dependencies must exist in either of the two places before your app loads. In the case of loading from `window`, adding your dependency as a regular `<script>` tag should work.

If you're looking for a more advanced form of dependency management for component files without the need for cli tooling, you can take a look at [rvc](https://github.com/ractivejs/rvc) which runs on top of RequireJS.